# Postgres - Select days with FAILURE status only

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having

I have table with multiple result per days for particular project_name (SUCCESS, FAILURE, ABORTED, UNSTABLE). I would like to select only days where only FAILURE status occurs - nothing else. There are some days with multiple status (after FAILURE it can be solved and get status with different time and set to SUCCESS).
How can I select only days with FAILURE status?

my query:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', time) AS group_day,
    build_result,
    project_name
FROM project_status
WHERE project_name = 'project_x'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', time), project_name, build_result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `group_day` and `project_name` and use `string_agg()` in the `HAVING` clause to set the condition that the only value of `build_result` is `'FAILURE'`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', time) AS group_day,
       project_name
FROM project_status
WHERE project_name = 'project_x'
GROUP BY group_day, project_name
HAVING string_agg(DISTINCT build_result, ',') = 'FAILURE'
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys. it seems working properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and *having*:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', time) AS group_day, project_name
FROM project_status
WHERE project_name = 'project_x'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', time), project_name
HAVING MIN(build_result) = MAX(build_result) AND
       MIN(build_result) = 'FAILURE'
```